# How to know the file system of my USB memory from the terminal?

Tags: mount

I have connected a USB memory to my PC. It has been automatically mounted and I can access it from `/media/...`.

How can I know the file system of this memory from the terminal?

Comment: why the downvote? Leave a comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `mount | grep ^/`. You'll get something like this:

```
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
```

As you can see, the file system is ext4 in my case.